# Alert position in JavaFx changing to default after I'm pressing button again

Tags: javafx, position, alert

I'm showing an alert message on button click at specific position.

I've done but position is changing to default position as I'm pressing a `button` for second time.

> MessageController.java

```
 public class MessageController implements Initializable {

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        alert.setTitle("Message");
        alert.setHeaderText("You clicked button");
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ((Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()).setX(50);
        ((Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()).setY(50);
    }
```

> Message.fxml

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="message.MessageController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

> Message.java(main class)

```
public class Message extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Message.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Same behavior if I use setX and setY where I'm showing an alert inside method

```
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    alert.setTitle("Message");
    alert.setHeaderText("You clicked button");
    ((Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()).setX(50);
    ((Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()).setY(50);
    alert.show();
}
```

> Above code also throws `NullPointerException` after clicked button for second time.

How to set fixed position of `Alert`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

If you assign your `Alert` an owner `Window` the problem goes away. And you should not be using:

```
((Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()).setX(50);
((Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()).setY(50);
```

To set the `x` and `y` properties. Use the following instead:

```
alert.setX(50);
alert.setY(50);
```

***Note:** See the documentation of [`Dialog`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html), the superclass of `Alert`, for more information.*

For example:

```
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    alert.initOwner(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
    alert.setTitle("Message");
    alert.setHeaderText("You clicked button");
    alert.setX(50);
    alert.setY(50);
    alert.show();
}
```

Another option, if you don't want to assign an owner, is to use a new `Alert` instance each time rather than reusing a single instance. The [answer by Ahmed Emad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58366907/6395627) shows an example of this.

---

## Long Answer

Note this all relates to implementation details.

The reason the `Alert` or, more generally, `Dialog` is centered on the screen when you show it the second time is a quirk (possibly a bug?) of the implementation. The code responsible for the behavior is in the package-private `javafx.scene.control.HeavyweightDialog` class. When you show the dialog the following method is called:

> ```
> @Override public void show() {
>     scene.setRoot(dialogPane);
>     stage.centerOnScreen();
>     stage.show();
> }
> ```

The exact same procedure is followed for `showAndWait()` except it calls `stage.showAndWait()` instead of `stage.show()`. As you can see, the `centerOnScreen()` method is invoked before the `Stage` is shown. However, the `Stage` used by the dialog is a custom anonymous class that overrides `centerOnScreen()`:

> ```
> final Stage stage = new Stage() {
>     @Override public void centerOnScreen() {
>         Window owner = HeavyweightDialog.this.getOwner();
>         if (owner != null) {
>             positionStage();
>         } else {
>             if (getWidth() > 0 && getHeight() > 0) {
>                 super.centerOnScreen();
>             }
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

You don't specify an owner so the `else` path is executed. This is where the quirk comes into play. Before the dialog has been displayed the calls to both `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` return `NaN` which is not considered to be greater than `0`, which means the super implementation of `centerOnScreen()` is not invoked and the `Stage` uses the `x` and `y` values you explicitly set. But then the second time you display the dialog both `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` return numbers greater than `0` which means `super.centerOnScreen()` is invoked and that method overrides any explicitly set `x` or `y` values.

If you do assign the dialog an owner, however, the `super.centerOnScreen()` method will never be invoked; instead, the `positionStage()` method is used. That method is used to center the dialog over its owner but, unlike `centerOnScreen()`, it respects any explicit values set for the `x` and `y` properties.

This means one solution is to simply assign your `Alert` an owner and it will always be displayed in the position you want it to. Unfortunately, I don't believe you can solve the problem elegantly if your `Alert` has no owner. One option is to set `x` and `y` after it has been shown but that may or may not lead to the dialog being displayed in the center of the screen and then jumping to the position you set—not exactly an ideal experience for your end users. This is assuming you must continue using the same `Alert` instance. If using a new `Alert` instance each time is acceptable then that would fix the problem as well.

Also you don't need to use:

```
((Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()).setX(50);
((Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()).setY(50);
```

In order to set the `x` and `y` values. For one, the `setX` and `setY` methods are declared in the `Window` class and so the cast to `Stage` is unnecessary.  But more importantly the `Dialog` class also declares `x` and `y` properties. The implementation even delegates to the `FXDialog` implementation which, in the case of `HeavyweightDialog`, simply sets the value on the internally used `Stage`; in other words, calling:

```
alert.setX(50);
alert.setY(50);
```

Does the exact same thing (mostly, see below).

On top of that, using `getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()` is the cause of your `NullPointerException`. When you create a `Dialog` it has an initial `DialogPane` which is automatically added to a `Scene` which in turn is automatically added to the internal `Stage`. So the first time you don't get an NPE. However, when you close the dialog the following is called (from `HeavyweightDialog` again):

> ```
> @Override public void close() {
>     if (stage.isShowing()) {
>         stage.hide();
>     }
>
>     // Refer to RT-40687 for more context
>     if (scene != null) {
>         scene.setRoot(DUMMY_ROOT);
>     }
> }
> ```

As you can see, it replaces the root of the `Scene` which means the `DialogPane` no longer has a `Scene` and thus the NPE. This is another reason to use `Dialog#setX` and `Dialog#setY` instead. Note the `DialogPane` is made the root again in the `show()` and `showAndWait()` methods.

Keep in mind the fact a `Stage` is used is an implementation detail. From [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html):

> A Dialog in JavaFX wraps a `DialogPane` and provides the necessary API to present it to end users. In JavaFX 8u40, this essentially means that the `DialogPane` is shown to users inside a `Stage`, but future releases may offer alternative options (such as 'lightweight' or 'internal' dialogs). This API therefore is intentionally ignorant of the underlying implementation, and attempts to present a common API for all possible implementations.

You should only use the API provided by `Dialog` and `DialogPane` and not assume anything about the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want by making the the button create the dialog when you click it not as a class member so your controller will look like so

```
public class MessageController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Message");
        alert.setHeaderText("You clicked button");
        alert.setX(50);
        alert.setY(50);
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    }
}
```

And the reason you got `NullPointerException` earlier because you were trying to get the stage of the dialog which doesn't exist before the `alert.show()` in the button click function

Comment: "_And the reason you got NullPointerException earlier because you were trying to get the stage of the dialog which doesn't exist before the alert.show() in the button click function_". Not quite. The `Stage` does exist and is accessible before the first call to `show()`. It's trying to get the `Stage` after the `Alert` has been closed that's the problem (explained in my answer).